# JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x2d when delete a local reference in native method

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In a native method, I declare a `jstring` local reference, after finish with it, I use DeleteLocalRef to delete it ref, but it always reports an error. I've read many websites about JNI reference, but most topics suggest the error maybe cause by use local reference cross the method, but in my case, the `jstring` object is declared and in the same function, So I'm confusing what's wrong with my code.
Below is my code:

```
 //jObj is a global reference
 int GetStringField( JNIEnv *env,jobject& jObj, string strFieldName, string& strValue ){
    g_nTestTime++;
    LOGD("GetStringField  %d", g_nTestTime);
    strValue = "";

    jclass clazz = NULL;
    jfieldID fid;
    jstring j_str = NULL;
    const char *c_str = NULL;

    clazz = env->GetObjectClass(jObj);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        LOGE("Get jObj class object failed in %s!", "GetStringField");
        return -1;
    }

    fid = env->GetFieldID(clazz, strFieldName.c_str(), "Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (fid == NULL) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
        LOGE("can not found %s ref in %s!", strFieldName.c_str(), "GetStringField");
        return -1;
    }

    j_str = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(jObj, fid);
    if (NULL == j_str)
    {
        LOGE("Get String object [%s] value failed in %s!", strFieldName.c_str(), "GetStringField");
        env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
        return -1;
    }

    c_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(j_str, NULL);
    if (c_str == NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else{
        strValue = c_str;
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(j_str, c_str);

    LOGD("Before env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz)!"); 
    DumpReferenceTables(env);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);

    LOGD("After env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz)!");
    DumpReferenceTables(env); // the dump shows 'j_str' still in the local reference table

    env->DeleteLocalRef(j_str); //JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x2d (index 11 in a table of size 10)

    LOGD("After env->DeleteLocalRef(j_str)!");
    DumpReferenceTables(env);

    return  0;
}
```

DumpReferenceTables is a VMDebug class method to dump ReferenceTables,below is his code:

```
void DumpReferenceTables(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jclass vm_class = env->FindClass("dalvik/system/VMDebug");
    if(NULL == vm_class)
        return ;
    jmethodID dump_mid = env->GetStaticMethodID( vm_class, "dumpReferenceTables", "()V" );
    if(NULL == dump_mid)
        return ;
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod( vm_class, dump_mid );
    env->DeleteLocalRef(vm_class);
}
```

The logcat in [here](https://pastebin.com/QMb4GbJb).

Comment: See this ;-          https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

Comment: `//jObj is a global reference`?  How is that saved?  Post *that* code too.

Comment: I would suggest to use PushLocalFrame() and PopLocalFrame() instead of local ref micromanagement. You can wrap it in C++ to take advantage of [RAII](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)