# NewStringUTF()/DeleteLocalRef() produces JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local

Tags: android, java-native-interface

This may be related to [JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x2d when delete a local reference in native method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510333/jni-error-app-bug-accessed-stale-local-reference-0x2d-when-delete-a-local-ref), however that question received no answers.

I had Android Studio generate a skeletal "Native C++" app and then modified native-lib.cpp as follows:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject /* this */)
{
    jstring jniHeader = env->NewStringUTF("x-foo");
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jniHeader);    // FAILS HERE
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

When I step through this in the debugger, I get this error:

```
09-09 17:23:25.371 7512-7512 E/example.jnites: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local 0x79  (index 7 in a table of size 7)

[ 09-09 17:23:25.372  7512: 7512 F/example.jnites ]
java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x79
java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from java.lang.String  com.example.jnitest.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()
```

Are you not supposed to call DeleteLocalRef() on strings? The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) don't say.

I tried using `PushLocalFrame()`/`PopLocalFrame()` instead, and still got the same results.

I tried creating a global reference and that only changed the error to `JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Global 0x2a52`

---

Additional information:

- Android emulator is running API 30
- build.gradle specifies compileSdkVersion 29, targetSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 28.
- Android studio 4.2.2, Runtime version 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264 x86_64
- This is on a Mac

Comment: How was `JNIUtils::_jvm` created, and is this code running in the same thread or a different thread?

Comment: It's basically a global set from env->GetJavaVM() the first time any function in my module is called. I should stress that this is a very small part of a very large module, and everything else seems to work just fine.

Comment: This code is very likely running on a different thread from the one where _jvm was obtained. I was under the impression that a single instance of _jvm is valid for all threads.

Comment: But I might be wrong about that; let me explore that.

Comment: Looks like I have a chicken-and-egg problem. I have a chunk of code which is being executed in another thread and has neither jvm nor env pointers, and it can't get one without already having the other.

Comment: *I tried using `PushLocalFrame()`/`PopLocalFrame()` instead, and still got the same results.*  Tried how?  Without calling `DeleteLocalRef()`?

Comment: Correct. I used push/pop instead of DeleteLocalRef(). I'm starting to think that @Botje is correct in that the jvm pointer is only valid for one thread. Although if that's true, then why have separate jvm and env pointers at all? And more importantly, what can C++ code do if it has neither? The problem is that my code is being called from a generic API library that runs on multiple platforms and has no Android-specific information. I'm thinking of using thread-global variables to cache the jvm and env pointers.

Comment: OK, I set a bunch of breakpoints and ran my code. There are at least two unique JNIEnv pointers, one per thread, but the JavaVM pointer is always the same, reinforcing my belief that the JVM is global to the process. _(Edit: I know it's possible to create more than one JVM for a process, but I'm not doing that.)_

Comment: Update: my assumption was correct, there is only one global JVM object. While Java allows you to have more than one, Android enforces that there can be only one. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni

Comment: Unbelievable. The problem only happens if I set a breakpoint in the function that's allocating and freeing the string. This is using Android Studio's debugger.

Comment: OK, I've reproduced the problem with the very tiny sample app that Android Studio itself generated. I've edited my question to include the complete C++ source code generated by AS, plus two lines added by me to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug in the Android Studio debugger and/or the JVM. My code is correct as written, but throws an error if you single-step through it in the debugger.

Leaving the question open in case someone has more to add, or a fix for the problem.

Comment: Could you edit the question with the versions of Android and Android Studio involved? That way someone who finds this issue in five years will know whether it still applies or not.

Comment: @Botje I've edited my question to add version info